# AEM: Is there any way to retrieve inherit component properties in sightly or js?

Tags: javascript, java, aem, sightly, aem-6

I am trying to create href links for SEO. Now my use case is that I have to create a new navigation component (that would be inherit in child pages) and if multilanguage is selected in that component only then SEO links should be visible.

As I have to show SEO links in head.html, so is there any way to retrieve inherit components in sightly or js, so that I can check wether multilaguage is selected or not?

If no,

There is a way through java using componentinheritancevaluemap,
If any one can provide a sample code of that, it could be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Child pages do not inherit (through Sling resourceSuperType inheritance) from parent pages so there is no direct access to properties from the parent tree. However, you can walk the page tree in your Use Object and retrieve those values. Here’s an example of an [inherited field dialog widget implementation](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/commons/editor/dialog/inherited/InheritedField.java) and also an [usage example in a component’s Sling Model](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/internal/models/v1/PageImpl.java#L147).

I do recommend you use Java POJO or Sling Models objects as they’re considerably more performant than the JS Use Objects.